# c# Splitting Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form with a primary tab control and multiple tabs (tabTest1, tabTest2, ..., tabSettings). How can I split the single file generated by designer into smaller, more manageable files? I tried using `partial class` but this isn't ideal for two reasons.

1. The event handler's and designer code (regardless of which tab they are on) are generated on the same file.
2. I have to be overly verbose in my variable descriptions to keep things straight (tab to tab). For example, several "test tabs" have an "encoder" variable so I have to do something like `testOneEncoderValue`, `testTwoEncoderLabel`, etc. Very annoying.

I am sure there is a better way (hence this question). Forgive my n00bness.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a custom (container / user control) class respective of each "tab" and the controls in it.  Then, just slap those individual controls on your tabbed interface as a single control.  This way, it keeps the controls together as a single unit without the criss-cross... especially if you are dealing with say.... 100 controls?

Container/user control 1 has its (example)30 controls respective to Tab1

Container/user control 2 has its (example)18 controls respective to Tab2

Container/user control 3 has its (example)50 controls respective to Tab3

Then, on your main window of the tabbed page, just put the single control on each respective page.  They are now in more manageable sub-components.

Comment: So I added a user control to my project and just adjusted its size. How do I add this UC to the tab page in designer mode? Or does it have to be done through code?

Comment: @Jon, once created and the project recompiled to see it as a control, it should be visible within your "Toolbox" when doing design work.  You should then be able to drag that onto you form just as if it was any other window control.  What version of VS are you running.

Comment: Great, Thanks DRapp! I am referencing several other .dlls and I found it hiding among their controls. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Best would be to try to isolate functionality of each tab as separate entity and create UserControl for each tab you have. If tabs themselves are too large, your UserControl can be further split into more sub controls to get finer granularity. Your user controls need not be isolated from each other, they can expose data, methods or events so they can be composed together on main form.

If you want to keep everything on same form, you can't have it both ways unfortunately. You either have to:

1. Keep everything in same designer.cs file if you want to use VS Designer to edit your form
2. Manually write UI code and organize it as you wish